# My Apache rewrite code (provided) in .htaccess works, but also re-writes favicon.ico. How fix?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have always used this simple code to have all requests use one index.php file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .? index.php [L]
```

However, I have just found that it's also re-writing the favicon.ico file.

My understanding is that the code above should rewrite only index.php and no other file or directory. Am I wrong? How would I fix this?

Comment: As it is, your code rewrites any request to a file or directory _that doesn't exist_ into index.php. Does `favicon.ico` exist?

Comment: I've worked it out. The favicon.ico didn't have suitable file permissions (so I suppose it was like it didn't exist). At least I know my code was fine!

Answer (score 1):

Just add an exception for it in your rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon.ico [NC]
RewriteRule .? index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. See my comment above. This shouldn't be needed.